# How can I consistently sink a basket?

Tags: overwatch

You know that basketball hoop in the spaceship holding room before the game begins? I was in a game where someone scored a basket (and made the confetti and sound effect play) before each round started, but I haven't found a technique for even hitting it close. Is there a consistent way to land a two-pointer, perhaps with a specific ball or a specific character's melee/ability?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

And without "cheating" the technique is quite simple.

1. position yourself so the ball is exactly between you and the hoop.
2. You duck and look at the hoop trough the ball
3. You melee (with any character)

This will almost certainly get it on the hoop and with a bit of practice you'll be able to land them.

Answer (score 5):

With Symmetra, you only need to use your primary fire at a certain distance to pick up the ball and carefully place it in the basket. For the definition of a 2 pointer... well... Let's call this one a dunk :P